# Find all occurences of a string in 4th Column and replace 7th column with specific text - bash

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, search

I am beginner to bash scripting and I am not able to find a solution to my problem. 
I have a list of strings like in input.txt file separated by newline character:

```
TATAMOTORS
TCS
RELIANCE
MARUTI
```

I have another file target.txt with more than 1000 lines in csv format which is of the following format:

```
124,1940000,792,TATAMOTORS,172.1.1.21,mode1,12:00:00,1,21,0,23,23,014,1000,alive,1,17,23
```

I want to replace the time in field number 7 to 24:00:00 for all the lines where the column 4 (here TATAMOTORS) matches with any of the lines in input.txt file.

Can I do this with a simple bash command/script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using bash and sed:

```
while read token; do
   sed -i "/$token/{s/,[^,]*/,24:00:00/6}" target.txt
done < input.txt
```

This script reads `input.txt` line by line and put line value into `token` variable.

`sed` performs replace the 6th match of the regexp only for line that contains `$token`.

`-i` option specifies that files are to be edited in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple Awk command/script:

```
awk -F, '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
  NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} 
  $4 in a {$7 = "24:00:00"}
  1
' input.txt target.txt
```

Comment: a[$1] alone defines an (empty) element; no reason to assign a value to it so ++ could be omitted. or missing something else?

Comment: @GiannakopoulosJ yes I believe that's the case (I almost wrote it that way) but based on others' examples it seems to be more idiomatic to use either `a[$1]++` or `a[$1]=1`